# Algorithm to find meeting time slots where all participants are available

Tags: schedule

Came across this question in an interview blog. Given free-time schedule in the form `(a - b) i.e., from 'a' to 'b'` of `n` people, print all time intervals where all `n` participants are available. It's like a calendar application suggesting possible meeting timinings.

```
Example:

Person1: (4 - 16), (18 - 25)
Person2: (2 - 14), (17 - 24)
Person3: (6 -  8), (12 - 20)
Person4: (10 - 22)

Time interval when all are available: (12 - 14), (18 - 20).
```

Please share any known optimal algorithm to solve this problem.

I am thinking of the following solution.

- Create a `currentList` of intervals that contain one interval from each person. Initially `currentList = [4-16, 2-14, 6-8, 10-22]`.
- Look for the `max_start` and `min_end` in `currentList` and output `(max_start, min_end)` if `max_start < min_end`; Update all intervals in `currentList` to have `start` value as `min_end`. Remove the interval that has `min_end` from `currentList` and add the next entry in that person's list to `currentList`.
- If `max_start >= min_end` in previous step, update all intervals in `currentList` to have `start` value as `max_start`. If for any interval `i`, `end > start`, replace that interval in `currentList` with the next interval of the corresponding person.

Based on the above idea, it will run as below for the given example:

```
currentList = [4-16, 2-14, 6-8, 10-22]   max_start=10 >= min_end=8

update start values to be 10 and replace 6-8 with next entry 12-20.

currentList = [10-16, 10-14, 12-20, 10-22] max_start=12 <= min_end=14

add max_start-min_end to output and update start values to 14. Output=[12-14]

currentList = [14-16, 17-24, 14-20, 14-22] max_start=17 >= min_end=16

update start values to be 17 and replace 14-16 with 18-25

currentList = [18-25, 17-24, 17-20, 17-22] max_start=18 <= min_end=20

add max_start-min_end to output and update start values to 20. Output=[12-14, 18-20]

currentList = [20-25, 2-24, - , 2-22]

Terminate now since there are no more entry from person 3.
```

I have not implemented the above though. I am thinking of a min-heap and max-heap to get the min and max at any point. But I am concerned about updating the start values because updating the heap may become expensive.

Comment: It's a trick question; 25 is not a valid time

Comment: @Bern, looking for an optimal solution. Didn't want to state the obvious :)

Comment: @CalleBergström Time as in not wall clock time. It's just a representation.

Comment: @sachin2182 We aren't here to write your code for you. Make an attempt to solve it and if you can get it, then ask. Show what you've tried, and ask specific questions about the problems you're having.

Answer (score 15):

Got this today during an interview. Came up with an `O(N*logN)` solution. Wondering whether there is an `O(N)` solution available...

Overview: Join individual schedules into one list `intervals` --> Sort it by intervals' starting time --> Merge adjacent intervals if crossing --> Returning the availability is easy now.

```py
import unittest


# O(N * logN) + O(2 * N) time
# O(3 * N) space

def find_available_times(schedules):
    ret = []

    intervals = [list(x) for personal in schedules for x in personal]

    intervals.sort(key=lambda x: x[0], reverse=True)  # O(N * logN)

    tmp = []

    while intervals:
        pair = intervals.pop()    
    
        if tmp and tmp[-1][1] >= pair[0]:
            tmp[-1][1] = max(pair[1], tmp[-1][1])

        else:
            tmp.append(pair)
    
    for i in range(len(tmp) - 1):
        ret.append([tmp[i][1], tmp[i + 1][0]])    

    return ret


class CalendarTests(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_find_available_times(self):
        p1_meetings = [
            ( 845,  900),
            (1230, 1300),
            (1300, 1500),
        ]

        p2_meetings = [
            ( 0,    844),
            ( 845, 1200), 
            (1515, 1546),
            (1600, 2400),
        ]

        p3_meetings = [
            ( 845, 915),
            (1235, 1245),
            (1515, 1545),
        ]

        schedules = [p1_meetings, p2_meetings, p3_meetings]
       
        availability = [[844, 845], [1200, 1230], [1500, 1515], [1546, 1600]]

        self.assertEqual(
            find_available_times(schedules), 
            availability
            )


def main():
    unittest.main()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: In its current state it assumes a 24hour work day. What do you think would be the best way to add limits to working hours (900-1800) without affecting the time complexity? I was wondering if adding a busy time from (1800-900) would be the best option

Comment: OP is providing input of time intervals where people are available. It looks like you started with intervals where they are not available, and with this your approach gives correct solution. It may be a good idea to clarify this in the answer to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 9):

A starting point, still to optimize a bit, might be the following (code is in Python).
You have the following data (the `allPeople` list will be clearly created dynamically):

```
person_1 = ["4-16","18-24"]
person_2 = ["2-14","17-24"]
person_3 = ["6-8","12-20"]
person_4 = ["10-22"]
allPeople = [person_1, person_2, person_3, person_4]
```

What you might do is to create a list containing all the time slots of the day (i.e. `["0-1", "1-2", "2-3", etc.]` as follows:

```
allTimeSlots = []
for j in range(0,24):
    allTimeSlots.append(str(j) + "-" + str(j+1))
```

and then create a list called `commonFreeSlots`, which is made of all the time slots that are inside *each person's free time slot collection*:

```
commonFreeSlots = []
for j in range(0,len(allTimeSlots)):
    timeSlotOk = True
    for k in range(0,len(allPeople)):
        person_free_slots = parseSlot(allPeople[k])
        if allTimeSlots[j] not in person_free_slots:
            timeSlotOk = False
            break
    if timeSlotOk:
        commonFreeSlots.append(allTimeSlots[j])
```

Please note that the function `parseSlot` is just taking a list of strings (like `"2-14","15-16"`) and returning a list of hourly time slots (like `["2-3","3-4","4-5" etc.]` in order to make it comparable with the hourly time slot list `allTimeSlots` created above:

```
def parseSlot(list_of_slots):
    result = []
    for j in range(0,len(list_of_slots)):
        start_time = int(list_of_slots[j].split("-")[0])
        end_time = int(list_of_slots[j].split("-")[1])
        k = 0
        while (start_time + k) < end_time:
            result.append(str(start_time+k) + "-" + str(start_time+k+1))
            k += 1
    return result
```

If I run the above script, I get the following result:

```
['12-13', '13-14', '18-19', '19-20']
```

Of course you will have to still work a bit the output in order to aggregate the hours (and having `['12-14','18-20']` instead of the hourly version), but this should be easier I think.

The above solution should work always, however I'm not sure it's optimal, it probably exists a better one. But since you didn't share any attempt yet, I guess you'd just like some tips to get started so I hope this one helps a bit.

Comment: Nice idea, I haven't thought from this perspective! But I feel this is more of brute force method and for large intervals (1-100000), this will get expensive. I posted an idea of mine in the question. Let me know your thoughts.

Comment: @sachin2182 I had a look at your example but the logic is not very clear to me: you don't come out with the expected output at the end of your test. Do you? Moreover, this point is still unclear to me also: if these are time slots of the day, why do bounds sometimes go over 24? I get that (2-4) means that the person is free from 2 to 4, how can an input possibly be 25 or 1000000?

Answer (score 3):

Dmitry's solution is good enough for most scenarios, but here's another take with `O(k * N)` time and `O(k)` extra space, where N is the number of meetings, and k is the granularity of your time slots. If every meeting is known to be hourly, then k can be 24. If the meetings are held every 30 minutes, then k can be 48. k can go all the way up to 60 * 24 (your granularity is every minute in a day). You can also let k be the GCD of all times in minutes.

Overview: Make an k-sized array of booleans called A, where each index corresponds to availability in your time granularity. It begins with every slot available. Run over all meetings. Set the indexes between the start and end time of the meeting in A to False. In the end, A holds the free time slots common for everyone. The times must be in minutes for the algorithm to work.

```py
minutesInDay = 60 * 24


def minuteToString(time):
    hour = str(int(time / 60))
    minute = str(int(time % 60))

    if len(hour) == 1:
        hour = '0' + hour
    if len(minute) == 1:
        minute = '0' + minute

    return hour + ':' + minute


def stringToMinute(time):
    hour, minute = time.split(':')
    return 60 * int(hour) + int(minute)


def availableTimeSlots(meetings, k):
    freeTime = [True] * k
    step = int(minutesInDay / k)

    for meet in meetings:
        for i in range(int(meet[0] / step), int(meet[1] / step)):
            freeTime[i] = False

    result = list()
    openInterval = False
    beg, end = 0, 0
    for i, slot in enumerate(freeTime):
        if not openInterval and slot:
            openInterval = True
            beg = i
        elif openInterval and not slot:
            openInterval = False
            end = i
            beg = minuteToString(beg * step)
            end = minuteToString(end * step)
            result.append((beg, end))

    return result


def main():
    p1 = [
        ('9:00', '10:30'),
        ('12:00', '13:00'),
        ('16:00', '18:00'),
    ]

    p2 = [
        ('10:00', '11:30'),
        ('12:30', '14:30'),
        ('14:30', '15:00'),
        ('16:00', '17:00'),
    ]

    p3 = [
        ('00:00', '8:00'),
        ('12:00', '14:00'),
        ('18:00', '24:00'),
    ]

    meetings = [
        list(map(stringToMinute, meeting)) for p in [p1, p2, p3]
        for meeting in p
    ]
    print(meetings)
    print(availableTimeSlots(meetings, 48))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Nice - very easy to imagine! Will perform faster than `O(N*logN)` if the number of the meetings in a day `N > 2^1440` (schedule with minutes) and `N > 2^24` (hours only)  :)

Answer (score 3):

I prefer to take a slightly different approach that's set based! I'll let the language elements do the heavy lift for me. As you guys have already figured out I'm making some assumptions that all meetings are on the top of the hour with an interval length of 1 hour.

```py
def get_timeslots(i, j):
    timeslots = set()
    for x in range (i, j):
        timeslots.add((x, x + 1))
    
    return timeslots

if __name__ == "__main__":
    allTimeSlots = get_timeslots(0, 24)

    person1TimeSlots = get_timeslots(4, 16).union(get_timeslots(18, 24))
    person2TimeSlots = get_timeslots(2, 14).union(get_timeslots(17, 24))
    person3TimeSlots = get_timeslots(6,8).union(get_timeslots(12, 20))
    person4TimeSlots = get_timeslots(10, 22)

    print(allTimeSlots
        .intersection(person1TimeSlots)
        .intersection(person2TimeSlots)
        .intersection(person3TimeSlots)
        .intersection(person4TimeSlots))
```

Answer (score 2):

The below is the javascript solution for the problem. Its complexity is O(n^3) but since the time is finite it can be considered n^2

```js
function getFreeMeetingTime(allPeople) {
  // get a range of time in a day.
  // you can pass the min and max from the input if its not 0 to 24 hrs
  const allTimeSlotsInDay = getAllTimeSlots();
  let tempResult = [];
  
  for (const person of allPeople) {
    for (const time of person) {
      for (
        let i = Number(time.split('-')[0]);
        i < Number(time.split('-')[1]);
        i++
      ) {
        const val = `${i}-${i + 1}`;
        if (!tempResult.includes(val)) {
          tempResult.push(val);
        }
      }
    }
  }
  // merge the times in between. ex '4-5', '5-6' to '4-6'
  return mergeTime(
    allTimeSlotsInDay.filter((time) => !tempResult.includes(time))
  );
}

function mergeTime(timeArray) {
  const result = [];
  let i = 0;
  while (i < timeArray.length) {
    const arr = timeArray[i].split('-');
    let start = Number(arr[0]);
    let end = Number(arr[1]);
    let counter = 0;
    for (let j = i + 1; j < timeArray.length; j++) {
      const jarr = timeArray[j].split('-');
      const jstart = Number(jarr[0]);
      const jend = Number(jarr[1]);

      if (end == jstart || end >= jstart) {
        end = jend;
        counter++;
      }
    }

    i = counter === 0 ? ++i : i + counter + 1;
    result.push(`${start}-${end}`);
  }
  return result;
}

function getAllTimeSlots() {
  const result = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < 24; i = i + 1) {
    result.push(`${i}-${i + 1}`);
  }
  return result;
}

/**
 * Creating a sample data to test
 */

//sample time slots of persons where they are busy
const person_1 = ['5-6', '18-24'];
const person_2 = ['2-4', '17-24'];
const person_3 = ['6-8', '12-20'];
const person_4 = ['10-22'];

// Getting an array of time schedules where people are busy.
const allPeople = [person_1, person_2, person_3, person_4];

// get data back to result
const result = getFreeMeetingTime(allPeople);
console.log(result)
```

you can check the detailed code in the below link

https://www.hectane.com/blog/meeting-when-all-people-free

Answer (score 0):

Possibly naive solutions:

1.
For each participant create an integer representation of their schedule where each bit represents if they are free in that half hour / hour slot. Then do a Bitwise and of all strings.

2.
Alternatively, create N tables for N participants where Col1 = TimeSlot and Col2 = Free/Not and join them all.

Answer (score 0):

Calendar scheduling for 3 people (5 days of the week, 90 min slots using system Verilog multi dimensional associative array technique. This uses `foreach` loop with 2 variables as indexes to fetch the array values)

```
module calendar_scheduling;
  initial begin
    
string person1[string][string] = {
  "Monday": '{
    "0000":"No",
    "0130":"No",
    "0300":"Yes",
    "0430":"No",
    "0600":"Yes",
    "0730":"Yes",
    "0900":"No",
    "1030":"Yes",
    "1200":"No",
    "1330":"Yes",
    "1500":"No",
    "1630":"Yes",
    "1800":"Yes",
    "1930":"No",
    "21:00":"Yes",
    "2230":"Yes"
  },
  "Tuesday": '{
    "0000":"Yes",
    "0130":"No",
    "0300":"Yes",
    "0430":"No",
    "0600":"Yes",
    "0730":"Yes",
    "0900":"No",
    "1030":"Yes",
    "1200":"No",
    "1330":"Yes",
    "1500":"No",
    "1630":"Yes",
    "1800":"Yes",
    "1930":"No",
    "21:00":"Yes",
    "2230":"Yes"
  },
  "Wednesday": '{
    "0000":"Yes",
    "0130":"No",
    "0300":"Yes",
    "0430":"No",
    "0600":"Yes",
    "0730":"Yes",
    "0900":"No",
    "1030":"Yes",
    "1200":"No",
    "1330":"Yes",
    "1500":"No",
    "1630":"Yes",
    "1800":"Yes",
    "1930":"No",
    "21:00":"Yes",
    "2230":"Yes"
  },
  "Thursday": '{
    "0000":"Yes",
    "0130":"No",
    "0300":"Yes",
    "0430":"No",
    "0600":"Yes",
    "0730":"Yes",
    "0900":"No",
    "1030":"Yes",
    "1200":"No",
    "1330":"Yes",
    "1500":"No",
    "1630":"Yes",
    "1800":"Yes",
    "1930":"No",
    "21:00":"Yes",
    "2230":"Yes"
  },
  "Friday": '{
    "0000":"Yes",
    "0130":"No",
    "0300":"Yes",
    "0430":"No",
    "0600":"Yes",
    "0730":"Yes",
    "0900":"No",
    "1030":"Yes",
    "1200":"No",
    "1330":"Yes",
    "1500":"No",
    "1630":"Yes",
    "1800":"Yes",
    "1930":"No",
    "21:00":"Yes",
    "2230":"Yes"
  }
};
                           
string person2[string][string] = {
  "Monday": '{
    "0000":"No",
    "0130":"Yes",
    "0300":"No",
    "0430":"Yes",
    "0600":"Yes",
    "0730":"Yes",
    "0900":"No",
    "1030":"No",
    "1200":"No",
    "1330":"No",
    "1500":"No",
    "1630":"Yes",
    "1800":"No",
    "1930":"Yes",
    "21:00":"No",
    "2230":"Yes"
  },
  "Tuesday": '{
    "0000":"Yes",
    "0130":"Yes",
    "0300":"No",
    "0430":"Yes",
    "0600":"Yes",
    "0730":"Yes",
    "0900":"No",
    "1030":"No",
    "1200":"No",
    "1330":"No",
    "1500":"No",
    "1630":"Yes",
    "1800":"No",
    "1930":"Yes",
    "21:00":"No",
    "2230":"Yes"
  },
  "Wednesday": '{
    "0000":"Yes",
    "0130":"Yes",
    "0300":"No",
    "0430":"Yes",
    "0600":"Yes",
    "0730":"Yes",
    "0900":"No",
    "1030":"No",
    "1200":"No",
    "1330":"No",
    "1500":"No",
    "1630":"Yes",
    "1800":"No",
    "1930":"Yes",
    "21:00":"No",
    "2230":"Yes"
  },
  "Thursday": '{
    "0000":"Yes",
    "0130":"Yes",
    "0300":"No",
    "0430":"Yes",
    "0600":"Yes",
    "0730":"Yes",
    "0900":"No",
    "1030":"No",
    "1200":"No",
    "1330":"No",
    "1500":"No",
    "1630":"Yes",
    "1800":"No",
    "1930":"Yes",
    "21:00":"No",
    "2230":"Yes"
  },
  "Friday": '{
    "0000":"Yes",
    "0130":"Yes",
    "0300":"No",
    "0430":"Yes",
    "0600":"Yes",
    "0730":"Yes",
    "0900":"No",
    "1030":"No",
    "1200":"No",
    "1330":"No",
    "1500":"No",
    "1630":"Yes",
    "1800":"No",
    "1930":"Yes",
    "21:00":"No",
    "2230":"Yes"
  }
};

string person3[string][string] = {
  "Monday": '{
    "0000":"No",
    "0130":"Yes",
    "0300":"Yes",
    "0430":"Yes",
    "0600":"Yes",
    "0730":"Yes",
    "0900":"Yes",
    "1030":"Yes",
    "1200":"No",
    "1330":"Yes",
    "1500":"No",
    "1630":"No",
    "1800":"No",
    "1930":"No",
    "21:00":"No",
    "2230":"Yes"
  },
  "Tuesday": '{
    "0000":"Yes",
    "0130":"Yes",
    "0300":"Yes",
    "0430":"Yes",
    "0600":"Yes",
    "0730":"Yes",
    "0900":"Yes",
    "1030":"Yes",
    "1200":"No",
    "1330":"Yes",
    "1500":"No",
    "1630":"No",
    "1800":"No",
    "1930":"No",
    "21:00":"No",
    "2230":"Yes"
  },
  "Wednesday": '{
    "0000":"Yes",
    "0130":"Yes",
    "0300":"Yes",
    "0430":"Yes",
    "0600":"Yes",
    "0730":"Yes",
    "0900":"Yes",
    "1030":"Yes",
    "1200":"No",
    "1330":"Yes",
    "1500":"No",
    "1630":"No",
    "1800":"No",
    "1930":"No",
    "21:00":"No",
    "2230":"Yes"
  },
    "Thursday": '{
      "0000":"Yes",
    "0130":"Yes",
    "0300":"Yes",
    "0430":"Yes",
    "0600":"Yes",
    "0730":"Yes",
    "0900":"Yes",
    "1030":"Yes",
    "1200":"No",
    "1330":"Yes",
    "1500":"No",
    "1630":"No",
    "1800":"No",
    "1930":"No",
    "21:00":"No",
    "2230":"Yes"
  },
    "Friday": '{
      "0000":"Yes",
    "0130":"Yes",
    "0300":"Yes",
    "0430":"Yes",
    "0600":"Yes",
    "0730":"Yes",
    "0900":"Yes",
    "1030":"Yes",
    "1200":"No",
    "1330":"Yes",
    "1500":"No",
    "1630":"No",
    "1800":"No",
    "1930":"No",
    "21:00":"No",
    "2230":"Yes"
  }
};

foreach(person1[i,j]) begin
  //$display("The calendar values are as follows Time : %0s :  %0s  : %0s : %0s : %0s",i,j,person1[i][j],person2[i][j],person3[i][j]);
  if ((person1[i][j]==person2[i][j])&&(person2[i][j]==person3[i][j]))
    $display("All the three people are available at time %0s IST on %0s", j, i);
  end    
end
  
endmodule
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function getFreeMeetingTime(allPeople) {
  // get a range of time in a day.
  // you can pass the min and max from the input if its not 0 to 24 hrs
  const allTimeSlotsInDay = getAllTimeSlots();
  let tempResult = [];
  
  for (const person of allPeople) {
    for (const time of person) {
      for (
        let i = Number(time.split('-')[0]);
        i < Number(time.split('-')[1]);
        i++
      ) {
        const val = `${i}-${i + 1}`;
        if (!tempResult.includes(val)) {
          tempResult.push(val);
        }
      }
    }
  }
  // merge the times in between. ex '4-5', '5-6' to '4-6'
  return mergeTime(
    allTimeSlotsInDay.filter((time) => !tempResult.includes(time))
  );
}

function mergeTime(timeArray) {
  const result = [];
  let i = 0;
  while (i < timeArray.length) {
    const arr = timeArray[i].split('-');
    let start = Number(arr[0]);
    let end = Number(arr[1]);
    let counter = 0;
    for (let j = i + 1; j < timeArray.length; j++) {
      const jarr = timeArray[j].split('-');
      const jstart = Number(jarr[0]);
      const jend = Number(jarr[1]);

      if (end == jstart || end >= jstart) {
        end = jend;
        counter++;
      }
    }

    i = counter === 0 ? ++i : i + counter + 1;
    result.push(`${start}-${end}`);
  }
  return result;
}

function getAllTimeSlots() {
  const result = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < 24; i = i + 1) {
    result.push(`${i}-${i + 1}`);
  }
  return result;
}

/**
 * Creating a sample data to test
 */

//sample time slots of persons where they are busy
const person_1 = ['5-6', '18-24'];
const person_2 = ['2-4', '17-24'];
const person_3 = ['6-8', '12-20'];
const person_4 = ['10-22'];

// Getting an array of time schedules where people are busy.
const allPeople = [person_1, person_2, person_3, person_4];

// get data back to result
const result = getFreeMeetingTime(allPeople);
console.log(result)
```

min

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
Class sample{
/*Since I am in basic level of programming, many of the above explanation were bit hard for me so i came up with below solution which seems to be using simple steps. Still I am not very keen on Time and memory utilization here but answer seems to good for me*/


int[] hrs=new int[10];
    @Test
    public void findAvailableTimeSlots()
    {
        String[] person1= {"8-9","10-11","14-15","16-17"};
        String[] peenter code hererson2= {"9-10","12-13","14-15","16-17"};
        String[] person3= {"8-9","9-10","12-13","16-17"};
        String[] person4= {"8-9","11-12","13-14","16-17"};
        
        
        ArrayList<String[]> alp=new ArrayList<String[]>();
        alp.add(person1);
        alp.add(person2);
        alp.add(person3);
        alp.add(person4);
        
        ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> alPerHrs=new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
        
        //0. split the string with - and take the first part out
            //and convert it to number and store it in an int array
        
        
        for(int k=0;k<alp.size();k++)
        {
            ArrayList<Integer> alPer=new ArrayList<Integer>();
            String[] tmp=alp.get(k);
            for(int i=0;i<tmp.length;i++)
            {
                int tmp1=Integer.parseInt(tmp[i].split("-")[0].trim());
                alPer.add(tmp1);
                
                //1. Create an int array for each person with 08-05 PM (10 hours) each index marking an hour
                //2. Load the arrays with counter values wherever the person is available 
                //if he is available from 08-09 then increase the counter at 08
                loadHours(tmp1);
                
            }
            alPerHrs.add(alPer);
            System.out.println(alPer);
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(hrs));
        }
        System.out.println(alPerHrs);
        
        ArrayList<Integer> hoursAvail=new ArrayList<Integer>();
        //3. iterate thru each person and sum the counter at the index to see if the value is matching 
            //the total person available if so then add that time to final output list
        for(int i=0;i<hrs.length;i++)
        {
            if(hrs[i]==alp.size())hoursAvail.add((8+i));
        }
        System.out.println("hours available -->"+hoursAvail);
        
    }
    
    //load hours
    public void loadHours(int tmp)
    {
        if(!((tmp-8)>9))
        {
            hrs[tmp-8]++;   
        }
        else
        {
            //ignore since it's outside the business hours
        }
        
    }
}
```